# How can I pass a string variable to an OnExceptionAspect

Tags: postsharp

I wish to use a customized string for use in an OnExceptionAspect.

Say I created a string named "message" and then in:

```
Method A: message = "Could not record your personal data"
Method B: message = "Could not record your date of birth" etc.
```

Then, in the OnExceptionAspect, the string would be obtained from the method that threw the exception and include it in the resultant messagebox or whatever, for example:

```
If(MethodThatThrewException) has string "message";
  exceptionMessage = (MethodThatThrewExption).message;
```

Is the above possible or is there another way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I decided it's easier to pass the variable as a parameter to the aspect eg...

```
[ExceptionDialog(null, "This is my custom message")]
```